# RubyOnRails Design Issue: User-managed static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Crossposting note: This question has already been asked several days ago at https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/5430206)

I'm creating a web site for a user, which has a considerable amount of
static pages. The user, who has some knowledge in HTML and CSS and can
be tought how to use some simple erb-code snippets (for example, to
create a <%= link_to "...",root_path %>), should be able to add, change
and remove the static pages by himself.

I will describe the approach I came up with, but would be glad to hear
better ways how to do it:

My approach would be to use high_voltage
(https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) for dealing with those
pages. I would reserve a directory app/views/user_pages for the HTML and
erb files, and app/views/images/user for holding the images needed for
his pages. The user will be told to upload by FTP only to those two
directories (or I will provide a specially tailored upload page for
this).

I will also create an admin page, where the user can select, which of
those static pages should show up in the main menu, and maybe also some
sequence number for each page, so that the user also can control the
sequence of the static page links in the main toolbar. This allows the
user to first test how the static pages look on the net, before he
"commits" them to the general public. This will be important, if he
really uses <%...%> tags, because he won't have a Rails environment when
creating the pages.

What do you think about this design?

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION:

I'm here interested mainly in two issues:

- If I go with this design, will there be any technical problems regarding Rails, if I
  dynamically add pages and pictures? For example, would it be necessary to restart the Rails server?
- Otherwise, are there other approaches to my problem? My user can (and wants) to create HTML code, and this code will most likely contain text and pictures, no dynamic contents (i.e. no JavaScript). The user doesn't need to have the ability to create a whole, complete side from  to . It would be equally well to just let him create most of the , while I provide a general framework (for example, common navigation elements on top and on bottom).

Basically, the user will provide the HTML code and the pictures. My site will allow him to upload everything and provides some means to decide, from which time to which time the content is visible. I will also generate automatically links to this content.

For must of these items, I find it straightforward to implement. However, I am unsure on how to do this integration of dynamically uploading static pages and the handling of the image files belonging to them.

Comment: Usually with user-created content you'd be storing their actions as data, rather than making files on your system.  This is how wordpress works for example: making and editing page and post records.  Personally the thought of giving my users FTP upload access to my site fills me with horror.  Storing them as data also makes it a lot easier to validate, sanitize etc the content.

Comment: I totally agreed with the comment above, it's not good idea to provide FTP access to users. 

I recently worked on a project where the users had a very similar requirement. The solution was to implement Markdown (through Redcarpet gem), and customize some Redcarpet methods. Maybe you can research a little this approach and decide if is a good fit or not.

Comment: Well, the user *has* FTP (he owns the site), and he is *used* to upload his files using FTP all the time. But I see the advantage of storing the information as HTML data in the database. It makes it easy to incorporate it into my existing framework. But how about images? The user's HTML will contain images (<img> tags) - they have to end up in my file system, otherwise the <img> tags would not work.